# How should eggplant be stored?

Tags: storage-method, eggplant

I don't know if I should put it in the refrigerator or the pantry. Does it go in the crisper?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eggplant should be wrapped in plastic and refrigerated. It will last 5-7 days this way.

It can also be frozen 6-8 months with the following process:

> 1. Wash eggplant, peel and cut into 1/3 inch slices;
> 2. Blanch (plunge into boiling water) for four minutes in 1 gallon of boiling water to which 1/2 cup lemon juice has been added (to prevent discoloration) and chill quickly in ice cold water;
> 3. Drain off excess moisture, package in airtight containers or freezer bags and freeze immediately.

Source: [StillTasty](http://stilltasty.com/fooditems/index/17143)

Comment: Gah!  I should have refreshed new answers first! +1 for being faster than me :)

Comment: Fast like ninja!

Answer (score 3):

You should store your eggplant in a cool part of your fridge, in a plastic bag or (preferably) wrapped in plastic wrap.  It should last for a good week like this.

Alternately you can blanch and freeze it to store for 6-8 months however the texture will be different when you thaw it because the cell walls will have broken down some.  If you go this route, I recommend [this method](http://stilltasty.com/fooditems/index/17143) (from stilltasty.com)